# Using Bootstrap 4 variables in my file

Tags: webpack, sass, bootstrap-4

I want to use Bootstrap 4 variables on my own CSS rules (e.g. `$font-family-serif`). I'm using Webpack and importing the Bootstrap variables and functions in my scss file like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
```

When trying to compile, I get the following error:

```
font-family: $font-family-serif;
            ^
    Undefined variable: "$font-family-serif".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$font-family-serif` variable in Bootstrap 4. There is a `$font-family-sans-serif` variable.